# python:running command in the background

Tags: python, django

I have a fairly complex report generating work, which needs to be generated spaning through multiple tables. Final report is created in an excel sheet.The process takes anything between 10-20 minutes.

We have provided a Django web app for the client. Only issue if the client requests for a report, we are generating a URL and this takes time, and is an issue as far as the UI go.

I would like the task to be running behind, and when over, it can mail the client a link, with the report. What is the right strategy, and libraries to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use http://celeryproject.org/, it works like a charm, it has nice Django integration, it's very well documented and used by many.

Comment: +1 for celery. There's also something older called [gearman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gearman) that allows you to do things that won't "fit" into the request/response loop.

Answer (score 1):

May be the below program helps you.

### background.py

```
import subprocess

def background_execute(command):
    # launching the command
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True,stdout=True)
    p1.wait()
    print "Wait over, child exits"
    <Here you can add code to send mail>
```

Usage:

```
background_execute(["python sleep.py"])
```

### sleep.py

```
import time

print "I am in sleep script, and will sleep for 10 sec"
time.sleep(10)
print "exit from child"
```

Comment: This is not a great answer, since the code does not integrate with Django at all (which is what the original question asked for). Since subprocess.Popen can lead to weird results in Django, the developers discourage people from using it.